# MySQL Container Wait Timeout

Tags: docker, circleci

When trying to wait for the mysql docker container, I'm met with: `Problem with dial: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s`

```
# This config is equivalent to both the '.circleci/extended/orb-free.yml' and the base '.circleci/config.yml'
version: 2.1

# Orbs are reusable packages of CircleCI configuration that you may share across projects, enabling you to create encapsulated, parameterized commands, jobs, and executors that can be used across multiple projects.
# See: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/orb-intro/
orbs:
    node: circleci/node@5.0.1

# Invoke jobs via workflows
# See: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#workflows
workflows:
    version: 2
    node: # This is the name of the workflow, feel free to change it to better match your workflow.
        # Inside the workflow, you define the jobs you want to run.
        jobs:
            - build_and_test:
                    # This is the node version to use for the `cimg/node` tag
                    # Relevant tags can be found on the CircleCI Developer Hub
                    # https://circleci.com/developer/images/image/cimg/node
                    # If you are using yarn, change the line below from "npm" to "yarn"
                    filters:
                        branches:
                            only:
                                - master
executors:
    node:
        docker:
            - image: cimg/node:16.14.2

jobs:
    build_and_test:
        executor: node
        docker:
            - image: cimg/mysql:8.0
              auth:
                username: myuser
                password: $DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD
              environment:
                MYSQL_HOST: 127.0.0.1
                MYSQL_DATABASE: mydatabase
                MYSQL_USER: user
                MYSQL_PASSWORD: passw0rd
        steps:
            - checkout
            - run:
                    name: install dockerize
                    command: wget https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize/releases/download/v$DOCKERIZE_VERSION/dockerize-linux-amd64-v$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz && tar -C /usr/local/bin -xzvf dockerize-linux-amd64-v$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz && rm dockerize-linux-amd64-v$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz
            - run:
                    name: Wait for db
                    command: dockerize -wait tcp://127.0.0.1:3306 -timeout 10s
```

I do see that the container is installed under the `spin-up environment` step, so I believe it should be running:

```
Starting container cimg/mysql:8.0
cimg/mysql:8.0:
  using image cimg/mysql@sha256:76f5b1dbd079f2fef5fe000a5c9f15f61df8747f28c24ad93bb42f8ec017a8df
  pull stats: Image was already available so the image was not pulled
  time to create container: 21ms
  image is cached as cimg/mysql:8.0, but refreshing...
8.0: Pulling from cimg/mysql
Digest: sha256:76f5b1dbd079f2fef5fe000a5c9f15f61df8747f28c24ad93bb42f8ec017a8df
Status: Image is up to date for cimg/mysql:8.0
Time to upload agent and config: 369.899813ms
Time to start containers: 407.510271ms
```

However, nothing I've been able to look into has pointed me in the direction of coming up with a solution at this point.

Comment: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#docker => `name (optional) - String - The name the container is reachable by. By default, container services are accessible through 'localhost'`. `127.0.0.1` is not strictly equivalent to `localhost`. So you should either use `localhost` to reach your mysql service or better IMO, set an explicit name like `my-db-server` and use it wherever relevent. (this comment is only based on a documentation lookup, I'm not a circleci user at time being so I could not reproduce your problem nor check my propostion actually works).

Comment: @Zeitounator I've tried doing something with this as well as changing to localhost instead of 127.0.0.1, however, it made no difference. Still getting connection refused.

Answer (score 0):

look over [here](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/executor-types/#using-multiple-docker-images), your job should define like following, for test out sql container, you could just use `nc -vz localhost 3306`, but the sql docker take time to initialize, so wait for about 2 minutes before test that.

```
    jobs:
      build_and_test:
        docker:
            # Primary container image where all steps run.
            - image: cimg/node:16.14.2
            # Secondary container image on common network.
            - image: cimg/mysql:8.0
              auth:
                username: myuser
                password: $DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD
              environment:
                MYSQL_HOST: 127.0.0.1
                MYSQL_DATABASE: mydatabase
                MYSQL_USER: user
                MYSQL_PASSWORD: passw0rd
        steps:
            - checkout
            - run: sleep 120 && nc -vz localhost 3306
```

Comment: I tried setting and testing sleep at 120, 240 and 480, and all resulted in not being able to connect to localhost 3306.

Comment: interesting, I tested above in ubuntu with circleci local, successful